# Performing "Joinattributebylocation" in PyGQIS

Tags: pyqgis, syntax

I'm new to QGIS and PyQGIS. My task is to draw points on a map and find which points are in a specific area.
To accomplish this I have three shapefiles of which two contains similar data which are merged in to a single layer of small / big town locations (ToSO in the code).
The points are created from a CSV-file and converted to two different in-memory shapefiles since the file contains a mix of RT90 and SWEREF99TM coordinates which are again merged to a single in-memory shapefile (RTSWE)

I then use "Join attributes by location" with all geometric predicates selected with RTSWE as base and ToSO as the top layer which are then again joined with a third shapefile.

[image: GUI version of what i'm trying to do in PyGQIS]

I have accomplished this task using the GUI but I now seek to automate this using PyQGIS (Note that i'm using the built-in Python console and not a stand-alone script). This is the code I have so far

```
from qgis.core import *

#Load RT90 points from XXX
uri='file:///G:/Projects/XXX/testrt90.csv?delimiter=;&yField=RT90X&xField=RT90Y&crs=EPSG:3021'
layerRT = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'XXXPoints', 'delimitedtext')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerRT)

#Load sweref points from XXX
uri='file:///G:/Projects/SCB/testsweref.csv?delimiter=;&yField=SW99X&xField=SW99Y&crs=EPSG:3006'
layerSWE = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'XXXPoints', 'delimitedtext')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerSWE)

#Get all pointlayers
listLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('XXXPoints')

#merge pointlayers 
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", 
                             {'LAYERS':listLayers,
                             'CRS':3006,
                             'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

result = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Merged')[0]
result.setName('RTSWE')

#delete pointlayers
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layerRT)
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layerSWE)

#Begin joinattributebylocation
To = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('To2018_Swe99TM')[0]
So = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('So2015_Swe99TM')[0]

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers", 
                             {'LAYERS': [To, So],
                             'CRS':3006,
                             'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

base = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('RTSWE')[0]
top = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('ToSo')[0]


processing.run("qgis:joinattributesbylocation",{
                        "INPUT": base, 
                        "JOIN": top,
                        "PREDICATE":u'intersects',
                        "SUMMARY":0,
                        "KEEP":1,
                        "OUTPUT":'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

However I can not get the syntax for joinattributesbylocation to work with the following error

> core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
>
> Incorrect parameter value for PREDICATE

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget some parameters, here is the documentation for [`joinattributebylocation`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location)

You must add the parameters :

- `METHOD:[0]`
- `DISCARD_NONMATCHING:False`

And the parameter `PREDICATE` should be `PREDICATE:[0]` if you only want `intersects`

Edit: If you've already launched the algorithms with the GUI you can copy the Python code using the processing History (Ctrl+Alt+H) or in the processing tab click on History

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue. I used the history as a template to figure out what fields were missing and what they should contain.  I had to change the input and join fields from history with the actual layers ("top" and "base") from my code above, running the code with the same input as the history didn't cause an error but it did not provide any layer